# wrote the code as:"t=int(input()) for _ in range(t)" error in some test cases but "for _ in range(int(input())" it worked fine!Difference?

Tags: python-3.x

Exception Name: EOFError
Exception Message: EOF when reading a line
The code failed some test cases due to this error which was shown in line number 1,the test case failed where always different:

```
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    x=n%12
    if x==1:
        print(n+11,"WS")
    elif x==2:
        print(n+9,"MS")
    elif x==3:
        print(n+7,"AS")
    elif x==4:
        print(n+5,"AS")
    elif x==5:
        print(n+3,"MS")
    elif x==6:
        print(n+1,"WS")
    elif x==7:
        print(n-1,"WS")
    elif x==8:
        print(n-3,"MS")
    elif x==9:
        print(n-5,"AS")
    elif x==10:
        print(n-7,"AS")
    elif x==11:
        print(n-9,"MS")
    elif x==0:
        print(n-11,"WS")
```

This was the code which passed all the test cases:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    x=n%12
    if x==1:
        print(n+11,"WS")
    elif x==2:
        print(n+9,"MS")
    elif x==3:
        print(n+7,"AS")
    elif x==4:
        print(n+5,"AS")
    elif x==5:
        print(n+3,"MS")
    elif x==6:
        print(n+1,"WS")
    elif x==7:
        print(n-1,"WS")
    elif x==8:
        print(n-3,"MS")
    elif x==9:
        print(n-5,"AS")
    elif x==10:
        print(n-7,"AS")
    elif x==11:
        print(n-9,"MS")
    elif x==0:
        print(n-11,"WS")
```

So is there a difference when you take the input inside the loop and when you take the input outside one?

Comment: the contraint was t<10^5

Answer (score 1):

Both of your code snippets are raising `EOFError` but this was because I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on my keyboard, and `input()` is designed to raise `EOFError` in this case. But if I type the numbers on each line without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then both of your code snippets work just fine.

To answer your question, there is no difference whether you call `input()` inside or outside a loop. Since you're dealing with standard input which is a terminal, the EOFError comes from pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.